# ElasticSearch Completion Suggester - Does not return data

Tags: elasticsearch

Could you help me with ElasticSearch suggesting:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-suggesters-completion.html

1. I've created type in ES index

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/tass_suggest_test/_mapping/company?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'

```
{
   "company": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "inn": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "innSuggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion"
                }
            }
        }
}
'
```

Filled it with some amount of data

2. Now I'm try to get data

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/tass_suggest_test/company/_search?pretty' -d'

```
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 1,
    "query" : { 
        "wildcard" : { "inn" : "78200*" }
    }
}'
```

It's ok, I got some data:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 10,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "tass_suggest_test",
        "_type" : "company",
        "_id" : "23515589",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 23515589,
          "inn" : "7820056885",
          "innSuggest" : "7820056885"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I'm trying suggest query I got nothing

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tass_suggest_test/_suggest?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "company-suggest" : {
        "prefix" : "78200",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "innSuggest"
        }
    }
}
'

{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 10,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "company-suggest" : [
    {
      "text" : "7820056885",
      "offset" : 0,
      "length" : 10,
      "options" : [ ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion suggester uses the simple analyzer by default, so numbers were removed from the input field. If you want to preserve numbers you could use the whitespace analyzer of your suggest field:

```
{
   "company": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "inn": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "innSuggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion",
                    "analyzer": "whitespace"
                }
            }
        }
}
```